# WiX Customizing EULA for Localization

Tags: wix

I'm working on setting up an installer that can display different EULA's depending on the end user's localization settings in their OS.  I'm following [this tutorial](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/04/15/WiX-3-Tutorial-Custom-EULA-License-and-MSI-localization.aspx). My localization file (.wxl) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="LANG">1033</String>
  <String Id="LicenseRtf" Overridable="yes">\Lang\en-us\TestLicense.rtf</String>
  <String Id="WelcomeDlgTitle">{\WixUI_Font_Bigger}[ProductName] [ProductVersion] Setup</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

I'm pretty sure this part is working because it's definitely adding the version number in the Welcome Dialog Title.  As you can see, I've set a variable for a licenseRtf which can be overridden.  Now my main .wxs file looks like this:

```
<Dialog Id="LicenseAgreementDialogOverwritten" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlg_Title)">
    <Control Id="LicenseAcceptedOverwrittenCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="207" Width="330" Height="18" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="LicenseAcceptedOverwritten" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgLicenseAcceptedCheckBox)" />
    <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />          
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
      <Condition Action="disable">
        <![CDATA[ LicenseAcceptedOverwritten <> "1" ]]>
      </Condition>
      <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAcceptedOverwritten = "1"</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgBannerBitmap)" />
    <Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">     
      <Text SourceFile="$(var.EULADir)\!(loc.LicenseRtf)" />
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="112" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
      <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgDescription)" />
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgTitle)" />
  </Dialog>
```

The key in this code (I think) is the line that sets the Text Sourcefile for the EULA.  You can see I've set the source file to look in this location: ***SourceFile="$(var.EULADir)!(loc.LicenseRtf)"***.  The variable EULADir is stored in my Config.wxi file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <?define EULADir = "C:\SomeLongPathOnMyMachine\EULA" ?>
</Include>
```

So, with this code I would expect the installer to check my EULA directory and load up my rtf file... however, when I run my installer the EULA that is displayed is the default EULA (ie. Lorem Ipsum etc.)  Does anyone know why it's not properly loading my rtf EULA file?

Comment: Did you check this one? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/04/15/WiX-3-Tutorial-Custom-EULA-License-and-MSI-localization.aspx

Comment: Yes.  I linked that tutorial in the first paragraph.  I think the issue is that I need to create a custom sequence of dialogs... one that links to my new LicenseAgreementDialogOverwritten dialog created above.

Comment: huh... the link was lost in the SO app... ok...

Comment: Did you check if `LicenseAgreementDialogOverwritten` is acutally used instead of the standard dialog?